# How to Call Async Task<ActionResult> Method in a Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an `async Task<ActionResult>` method in `CompanyInfoController` and I want to call this method in a service class (`ProductService`). How can I call this method and use the result list (`companyInfo`) in a service method?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetCompanyInfo")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetCompanyInfo(List<int> companyId)
    {
        var section = this._configuration.GetSection("Company");
        string uri = section.GetValue<string>("Host");
        string endpoint = section.GetValue<string>("CompanyInfo");

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string idContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(companyId);

            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(idContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var operationResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyInfoResultJSON>(content);

                var companyInfo = operationResult.CompanyInfo.SelectMany(x => x.CompanyInfoList).ToList();

                return Ok(companyInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```

My `ProductService` :

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;
    public ProductService(DBContext dbContext)
    {
        this._ dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Products> GetCompanyProductList(List<int> companyId)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        var products =_ dbContext.Products.Where(x => x.ProductionDate < today).ToList();
        foreach (item in companyId)
        {
            if (products.Any(x => x.companyId == item.companyId)
            {
                foreach (product in products)
                {
                    products.CompanyName =??
                  // In here, I want to get the companyInfoList elements.
                 }
            }
        }
      return products;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post ProductService pls. And point where are you going to use the action.  I doubt that  the Service needs ActionResult method.

Comment: @Serge I will edit the post, I need to companyInfo list to update the some rows of the Product list.

Comment: Side note.... Don't use HttpClient in a `using` block/statement and don't Dispose it. Plenty of resources across the internet and SO explaining why.

Comment: Why don't you take a dependency on `IProductService` in the controller and just call the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create special method that return API result and put it in Common class for example:

```
    public static async Task<List<CompanyInfo>> GetCompanyInfo(List<int> companyId)
    {
       if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                

                companyInfo;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
      
    }
```

after this you can call  it from your controller

```
     HttpPost]
    [Route("GetCompanyInfo")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetCompanyInfo(List<int> companyId)
    {
         var companyInfo=Common.GetCompanyInfo(companyId);
         if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                  return Ok(companyInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Not found");
            }
    }
```

and the same way you can call it  from your service

There is another way that maybe fits you better. In  this case you don't need Common

```
public class ProductService:IProductService
{
public  async Task<List<CompanyInfo>> GetCompanyInfo(List<int> companyId)
   .... the same code as it in  Common above
}
```

and your controller

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
          private readonly IProductService _service
        public CompanyController(IProductService service)
        {
            _service=service;
         } 
       HttpPost]
    [Route("GetCompanyInfo")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetCompanyInfo(List<int> companyId)
    {
          .... _service.GetCompanyInfo
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Thnx, it works, I tried the second solution. But I guess, ı should use the first one because I need this companyInfoList in the other services.

Comment: You can combine  first and the second one too. It depends on.